# Linking v-model in child to parent value vue js

Tags: javascript, data-binding, vue.js

I have a vue component which is as follows and in the child template I have a text input which I want to use v-model to link it to a var in the parent. But its not working. 
How would I be able to achieve this?

I'm currently using Vue.js 1.23 (needing to use it for certain reasons so upgrading isn't an option)

Thank you

```
// this is in my Vue app
textWidget: ''

// this is called directly in the page.html
<text-widget v-show="getCurrentWidgetType() == 'text-widget'" :textWidget="textWidget"></text-widget>

// declaring the component just before my main vue app
Vue.component('text-widget', {
    template: `{% include('templates/widgets/text.html.twig') %}`,
    date: function () {
        return {
            textWidget:textWidget
        }
    }
})
```

Update :

```
// declared just before my Vue app
Vue.component('text-widget', {
    template: `{% include('templates/widgets/text.html.twig') %}`,
    props: ['textwidgetmodel']
})

// text input in the component child
<input type="text" v-model="textwidgetmodel">

// html in the main html page
// this input was just for testing. This confirmed that the props binding did indeed work, 
// the only problem is it seems to be a one way binding from parent to child. 
// I assume this because when I change the value with the text input below then it changes the value even in the component element. 
// But when a value in inputted into the child text input nothing happens to the value in the partent
<input type="text" v-model="textWidget" />

<text-widget v-show="getCurrentWidgetType() == 'text-widget'" :textwidgetmodel=textWidget></text-widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I guess there is somewhere the input element that has model binded to the `textWidget`, something like this:

```
<input type="text" v-model="textWidget"/>
```

And you want to send this to your child component via props, so you did It like this

```
<text-widget v-show="getCurrentWidgetType() == 'text-widget'" :textWidget="textWidget"></text-widget>
```

This is almost good, but not enough because props in template should be formatted in the kebab-case, so this is correct setup

```
<text-widget v-show="getCurrentWidgetType() == 'text-widget'" :text-widget="textWidget"></text-widget>
```

And then you should define that prop into the component logic, so Vue can know what to use (you don't need data model here now, except you have some another component based data):

```
// declaring the component just before my main vue app
Vue.component('text-widget', {
    template: `{% include('templates/widgets/text.html.twig') %}`,
    props: ['textWidget']
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Ok so I need to change ":textWidget="textWidget" to ":text-widget="textWidget" but doesn't that also mean i need to change "props: ['textWidget']" to "props: ['text-widget']"? And if not why? does view do an automatic conversion between the two var type? Any way ill try this and let you know

Comment: OK just a few comments:
1. text-wiget and textWidget in the :bind ['textWidget'] and the v-model in the <input v-model="text-widget' /> (in the child component) dont work at all. This is probably down to being an older version of vue. in the end :textwidgetmodel=textWidget (no quotes around textWidget) worked for me
2. now when i link textWidget to another text input outside the child component in the regular html and link it via v-model that changes the value in the child but if i change the value in the child text box it wont change the parent var. Its just a one way bind.

Comment: But still thank you very much. I wouldn't have gotten this far with out you. Ill update my answer to the latest code

Comment: I don't really understand things you changed, but  there is a explanation about props naming http://v1.vuejs.org/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case